# New breaks sliding\gliding?

Tags: brakes, slipping

I have a hyundai coupe 2006.  I have just had new brake discs and pads added.

After the repair, In the first day of driving it on one occasion when I applied the brakes I heard a sound which sounds like 'dang'.  It also seem to me the car slows down rather then skids when braking but i'm not sure.

More importantly a few days later, I noticed on two occasions, when applying the brakes the car slided\glided when applying the brake.  this was dry weather and even if wet i when braking it will skid but not have a sliding\gliding effect. Not sure how to describe it but slipping may be another word. put another way, when i applied foot on the brakes, even through my foot I could sense something was wrong. On one of these two occasions I also heard the 'dang' sound again so it maybe related.

Can anybody advise me on this?  Had I been near traffic or people I would have hit them today so this is a bit of a concern.

thanks

Comment: Take everything apart and look if you accidentally placed the brake pads backwards (steel backing plate facing to the rotors)

Comment: Did you do the work or did you take it to a mechanic?

Comment: gave it to a mechanic.

Comment: You should have full control when braking, not sliding or slipping. Not sure what you are describing as *dang*, but sounds like you need to take it back to the mechanic to correct it.

Comment: Dang sounds should be repaired immediately.

Comment: Did you do the brake job or a shop?